# Flutter: Unable to load asset file 'car.png'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have added my asset files in my projects root directory, which contains images, fonts and sounds.

[image: assets folder]

Added the assets in `pubspec.yaml` file like this:

```yaml
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Then I try to add an image through `Image.asset` like the code below:

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      child: Text(
        "Uber",
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 22.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Text(
        "riyad", 
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      Image.asset("car_android.png") <-- like this 
    ],
  ),
);
```

But it shows me an exception that failed to load the asset:

```
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec: 
Unable to load asset: car_android.png
```

My traceback exception:

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: car_android.png
    
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:224:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:672:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "car_android.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#243b1(), name: "car_android.png", scale: 1.0)
```

I tried to run the command `flutter clean` to clean the cache and then run the app again, but the same problem occurred again, it failed to load the asset.

Comment: try adding every asset in one line, like this `assets/images/taxi.png`

Comment: Agree with @veneno and also, make sure to kill the app and run instead of hot reload. If in case the asset is included recently.

Comment: A Hot Restart will do the work.

Comment: I added to path to to asset in pubspec.yml like this "assets/images/".... shouldn't that be considered as a relative path ?? and adding image with Image.asset("car_android.png") would be considered as Image.asset("assets/images/car_android.png")...??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify Image path as follows

```
Image.asset("assets/images/car_android.png")
```

OR

```
Image(image: AssetImage("assets/images/car_android.png"))
```

The problem is flutter can't recognize where your image is exactly stored.

If the problem continues then try to do HOT RESTART this will solve your problem.

If you update pubspec.yaml file then run `flutter pub get` to update the libraries if your IDE doesn't update it automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Just to push a little further on Harshil Khamar answer which is correct and valid another consideration.
The assets in `pubspec.yaml` have to be under `flutter:` if you place another entry in between these then it does not know where the assets folder is. It may sound stupid, but I am sure I am not the only one to have done this.

```yaml
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  generate: true
flutter_intl:
  enabled: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/<<imagename>>
```

The `flutter_intl:` gets in the way as assets now think it is under `flutter_intl:` and not `flutter:`. If I am the only idiot then okay so be it.

```yaml
flutter_intl:
  enabled: true

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  generate: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/<<imagename>>
```

This solves the problem

Comment: To add, make sure to check that "assets" is properly indented under "flutter." The issue I had was these were both at the same level.

Comment: New to Flutter and didn't realize that indentation mattered beyond pretty formatting. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1.Check indentation. See image attached:

[image]

2. Image url path should be defined like this:

[image]

3. **Kill and reload app.** This seems essential after multiple checks of 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems can cause this problem:

1. you should stop your project and run it again without any `HOT RELOAD`
2. you should add a full directory of the image -> `assets/images/YOUR_IMAGE.png`

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is because you did not give the full path to your asset in the creation of an Image object.

```
 body: Column(
    children: [
      Text(
        "riyad", 
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      Image.asset("assets/images/car_android.png") <-- this like 
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Image.asset("assets/images/car_android.png")
2. flutter pub clean
3. flutter pub get
4. flutter run